# How to parse XML using special character / using Transform

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, using

I am using javax.xml.transform.Transformer to transform XML using XSLT. 
In one of the attribute name has special characters '/'. And it is failing with error "Attribute name "XXX" associated with an element type "XXXXXXX" must be followed by the ' = ' character". If I remove / in attribute name, XML is getting parsed. But it is not correct fix. We need to omit this special character while transforming XML. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, you have XML in which an attribute *name* contains a slash character?

According to the official XML specification, that is *not* a legal attribute name.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name

So your XML is illegal.  If you want to deal with "XML" documents with slashes in the attribute names, then you have to modify an off-the-shelf parser or write your own.  Since your XML is illegal, you cannot expect an XSLT parser to work.

Comment: is there any way to escape/ignore this (/) char from parsing against xsl. EX: my attibute name is HD/ONE="yes".

Comment: No, Suresh, you don't get it. Your XML is not well-formed. Its got nothing to do with the capabilities of XSLT. You can't do any thing with malformed XML. You should accept Ray's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to transform XML, you are trying to transform non-XML, because if you have "/" in an attribute name, then it isn't XML. So either change the content to be valid XML, or look for non-XML tools to do the job.